# (While studying rails tutorial)How to display user information on pages not related to the user controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

Sorry for the vague question.
In addition, I am not used to English, but I will do my best to communicate clearly.

It's time to set up the server and visit the page.

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in StaticPagesController#diary
Couldn't find User without an ID
Extracted source (around line #9):
7
8   def diary
9    @user = User.find(params[:id])
     @micropost = current_user.microposts.build if logged_in?
    end
   end
10
```

Explain this mistake.
I added a new page to the static page and tried to put the user's information there.
I wanted to add a diary posting function.

The structure of the file is as shown in the picture.
[the structure of the file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kahoQ.png)

In other words, I want to display user information on the diary page, but I thought I was getting an error that the user's ID could not be found.

I will put the information of the diary posting page where the error occurred.

```
app/views/stataic_pages/diary.html.erb

<% if logged_in? %>
  <div class="row">
    <aside class="col-md-4">
      <section class="user_info">
        <%= render 'shared/user_info' %>
      </section>
      <section class="micropost_form">
        <%= render 'shared/micropost_form' %>
      </section>
    </aside>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

partials

```
app/views/shared/_user_info.html.erb

<%= link_to gravatar_for(current_user, size: 50), current_user %>
<h1><%= current_user.name %></h1>
<span><%= link_to "view my profile", current_user %></span>
<span><%= pluralize(current_user.microposts.count, "micropost") %></span>
```

```
app/views/shared/_micropost_info.html.erb

<%= form_with(model: @micropost) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "Compose new micropost..." %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Post", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

and this is controller

```
app/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb

class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
  end

  def help
  end

  def diary
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @micropost = current_user.microposts.build if logged_in?
  end
end
```

route

```
app/config/route.rb

Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'sessions/new'
  get 'users/new'
  root "static_pages#home"
  get '/help', to: "static_pages#help"
  get '/search', to: 'searchs#search'
  get '/signup', to: 'users#new'
  get    "/login",   to: "sessions#new"
  post   "/login",   to: "sessions#create"
  delete "/logout",  to: "sessions#destroy"
  get '/diary',  to: "static_pages#diary"
  resources :users
  resources :microposts,          only: [:create, :destroy]
end
```

What I learned in the rails tutorial is that in the process of displaying a dedicated show page after logging in, add this to the user controller,

```
app/controllers/user


class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @microposts = @user.microposts.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      reset_session
      log_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new', status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password,
                                   :password_confirmation)
    end

   
    def correct_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      redirect_to(root_url, status: :see_other) unless current_user?(@user)
    end

   
    def admin_user
      redirect_to(root_url, status: :see_other) unless current_user.admin?
    end
end
```

It was to code something like this in the view page.

```
app/views/users/show.html.erb

<% provide(:title, @user.name) %>
<h1>
  <%= gravatar_for @user %>
  <%= @user.name %>
</h1>
<div class="col-md-8">
    <% if @user.microposts.any? %>
      <h3>Microposts (<%= @user.microposts.count %>)</h3>
      <ol class="microposts">
        <%= render @microposts %>
      </ol>
      <%= will_paginate @microposts %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

```
app/models/user.rb

class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :microposts, dependent: :destroy
    before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
    validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
    VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
    validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
                      format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                      uniqueness: true
    has_secure_password
    validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }
end
```

I put this code in the diary method,
just like displaying the profile on this user's show page.

@user = User.find(params[:id])
@microposts = @user.microposts.paginate(page: params[:page])

But I got the above error.
Is there something wrong with the model or DB relationship?
Isn't there a way to bring user information to the page that has nothing to do with the user controller?
Thank you for reading this far. If you have any questions, please leave a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is really how you're looking up the resource.

`@user = User.find(params[:id])` implies that the user id is part of URI. And since your route doesn't contain a `:id` segment `params[:id]` is `nil`.

But if you're displaying the "profile" of the current user you should get the user from the session:

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  # ...
  def diary
    @user = current_user
    @micropost = @user.microposts.build 
  end
end
```

You should also perform a check beforehand to ensure that the user is logged in.

Comment: If you're finished with the book I would scrap that app and move on. Its a very shakey foundation to build anything onto that contains a lot of questionable stuff just done for teaching purposes. You don't want to actually be deploying an app with the home made authentication system from the tutorial. While it might feel like you have invested a lot of work into it its because you're working at a snails pace when learning.

Comment: Thanks for the answers and comments!
That was a really big help!
Be careful not to put too much faith in books.
I will keep trying my best.